# Detecting user typing in a text box

Tags: javascript

I am using listeners to detect when a user finishes with textbox; when the text is value is changed, I am pasting their text on to the page using innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById("dateinput").addEventListener("change", function() {
     myDate(document.getElementById("dateinput").value);
     }, false);
```

Is there a way to listen for each key press to immediately paste the .value character by character as they type? I only want to do this while the textbox has focus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the events are `keyup`, `keydown`, `keypress` or, in contemporary browsers, `input` (which covers any user-initiated, non-programmatic, event in the relevant `<input>` element).

References:

- Events:

  - [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).
  - [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown).
  - [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress).
  - [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup).

Comment: Thanks that's so simple - I was trying all kinds of listeners in listeners! Thanks for the references.

Comment: if @david-thomas gave the correct answer, why don't you accept it?

Answer (score 5):

you can use an of keyup/keydown/keypress

```
document.getElementById("dateinput").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
     myDate(document.getElementById("dateinput").value);
     }, false);
```

you can use onpaste

```
 document.getElementById("dateinput").addEventListener("paste", function() {
         myDate(document.getElementById("dateinput").value);
         }, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was unaware of the paste!